# GCP VM instance cannot be accessed from external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been using GCP VM instance for REST API service (python flask).

it was assigned the external IP, and it was working fine.

However I got reported that it's not accessed via external IP.

Access via Internal IP from another VM instance is working fine.

What do I need to check?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your firewall rules, It might be that you need to create a new rule for this action:

You can create the rule with the following command:

```
gcloud compute --project=my-project firewall-rules create rule-for-test --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:[PORT] --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

The output should be something like:

```
Creating firewall...⠹Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project...l/firewalls/rule-for-test].
Creating firewall...done.
NAME              NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW     DENY  DISABLED
rule-for-test    default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:[PORT]        False
```

Also, Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) for further information.